# Android How can I create phone number edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, phone-number

my problem is creating EditText for phone numbers on Android.

I want to create EditText and when user entering phone number or letters, suggestions open drop-down list, like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AutoCompleteTextView in your layout and then have a look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

and then

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Answer (score 0):

In Graphic Layout, rightclick on edittext, in InputType menu, select any number type - number, phonetic

When you will run the app, the on screen keyboard will show only numbers

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to supply phone numbers or contact names as adapter to auto complete text view.

The below link provides you a tutorial to achieve this requirement.

[Fetch Phone contacts and Show it in AutoComplete TextView in Android](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2011/07/fetch-phone-contacts-and-show-it-in.html)